# How to validate dynamic content of web application which are database driven in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium.
I want to validate the dynamic content of a web application. All the content is coming from database on the basis of some business logic. I have done with google search but got no success to find a solution.
Below is the HTML code which contains dynamic data in `{{Curly}}` brackets

```
<label class="form-check-label form-text" [for]="plan.planId">
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio" [id]="plan.planId" name="selectPlan" [value]="plan.planId" [(ngModel)]="selectPlanOption">
            {{plan.device}} - <span id="deviceLabel" class="text-uppercase"></span> <b><span id="animatedText" class="animate-text yellow-text weight-class">
                ${{plan.price}} ({{plan.discount}})</span></b>
</label>
```

Also, I have a doubt.

> Is it good practice to validate dynamic content in Selenium?

Anyone help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which data are you trying to extract `plan.device` or `plan.price` or `plan.discount`?

Comment: I am able to access `plan.device` or `plan.price` or `plan.discount`. But these fields have dynamic content which could be anything. So my ques is how do I validate these fields.

Comment: Check out the published answer, once you are able to pull out the desired text, asserting the text would be no task.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to extract the *text* from `{{plan.device}}` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("label.form-check-label.form-text")))));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[@class='form-check-label form-text'][//input[@class='input-radio' and @name='selectPlan']]")))));
  ```